# PHP - Convert CMYK colour values to RGBA

Tags: php, rgba, cmyk

I need to convert CMYK values to RGBA values, but have yet to stumble upon an algorithm for this that just works.

I already have the RGBA to CMYK via the following:

- Convert RGBA to RGB
- Convert RGB to CMYK

Below are the algorithms I'm using for the above two bullet points:

**RGBA to RGB**

```
return substr($rgba, 0, -2);
```

... what? Nothing wrong with that! :D

**RGB to CMYK**

```
$c = 255 - $r;
$m = 255 - $g;
$y = 255 - $b;

$b = min($c, $m, $y);

$c = round(($c - $b) / (255 - $b));
$m = round(($m - $b) / (255 - $b));
$y = round(($y - $b) / (255 - $b));
$k = round($b / 255);

return sprintf('%s,%s,%s,%s', $c, $m, $y, $k);
```

---

On the return...

**CMYK to RGB**

```
$r = 255 - round(2.55 * ($c + $k));
$g = 255 - round(2.55 * ($m + $k));
$b = 255 - round(2.55 * ($y + $k));

if ($r < 0) $r = 0;
if ($g < 0) $g = 0;
if ($b < 0) $b = 0;

return sprintf('%s,%s,%s', $r, $g, $b);
```

**RGB to RGBA**

```
$min = min(array($r, $g, $b));
$a = (255 - $min) / 255;

$r = round(($r - $min) / $a);
$g = round(($g - $min) / $a);
$b = round(($b - $min) / $a);

$a = round($a);

return sprintf('%s,%s,%s,%s', $r, $g, $b, $a);
```

Now, doing the **reverse**, ie the previous two above, I get the output of converting CMYK to RGBA:

[image: cmyk]`168,107,107,108` *cmyk*

[image: rgba]`13,0,0,1` *rgba*

Clearly, reversing this is not the best way to go about converting CMYK to RGBA. Perhaps my algorithm is completely wrong? It might be expecting percentages instead of values? I'm not entirely sure as colour profiles are not my strong point.

Is there an algorithm available (in any language - it can be translated) to assist with the correct conversion of CMYK values to RGBA?

Comment: Could you add the algorithm you use to do the reverse of RGB -> CMYK? There might just be a mistake in the reversing

Comment: Those conversions never match 100%. So you might want to create a pair of algos that work very nicely together. Also RGBA is with an alpha-blending-level which is not part of CMYK so technically the Alpaha must be full-color, always. Better look for RGB / CMYK only so far and keep the alpha-blending out (always 1).

Comment: @Jasper Added for your amusement.

Comment: @hakre Well technically I'm doing that on the way back, I'm removing the alpha channel completely.

Comment: I'm not sure, but think that you shouldn't use alpha in the conversions, it doesn't vary the colour but its transparency, and the resulting color depends on the underlaying colour. So rgba(127,127,127, 0.5) would result in gray only if its over a white background, if it's over a red background it would be a darkish red.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that now, also you were already aware of that. For the other part what I know when I tried this years ago (no idea if I had success, it's really years ago), what I remember is that you can not simply round up or down but you need to calculate the gaps in the precision of the conversion and then map. E.g. black must stay black and white must stay white. I think I opted for such a strategy that time as those full colors seemed more important to me. However I'm not an academic dev, so there might be better thought-out models.

Comment: Also you should have a look into some ICC profiles, as rgb to cmyk and vice versa conversions are usually wrong, they are quite complex, as the RGB has a wider color range than CMYK

Comment: Hopefully after re-ordering the methods it's a little clearer, sorry about that. Really, it's *not* super important that the converted values are exact, approximate will do fine as these will be tweakable later on using a GUI.

Comment: Reversing your RGB2CYMK algorithm, I get `$r = 255 - round(255 * ($c - $c * $k - $k));` (and similar). I'm not saying your reversal using 2.55 is wrong, I just have no idea how you got to it.

Comment: @Jasper Neither do I, there's little information I can find on the internet for this, in my phpdoc I even put `@link <http://noideawhereIgotthis.com>`... Probably from bits and pieces from many different sites all over the internet. There seems to be neither a definitive algorithm, nor even an approximate one :(

Comment: There is no closed formula or algorithm whatsoever that would convert RGB to CMYK or vice versa with a decent quality. Color spaces are too complex to be defined mathematically. The formula you're using can be found all over the Internet; yet I cannot image any application where that poor formula would be useful. There is no way around using a color management system and a color profile (e.g. ISO Coated v2 300% from [eci.org](http://www.eci.org)). Unfortunately, I'm not a PHP expert and can't tell you how to use it in PHP. In Windows or .NET, it's built in.