# PIL Image Library Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, cmyk

How can I set percentage values (0% to 100%) on CYMK format instead of default values (0 to 255)?

Currently full ink black color is:

```
Image.new("CMYK", (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 255))
```

I want:

```
Image.new("CMYK", (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 100))
```

Comment: So you want to convert `100` to `255`? How about `100 * 2.55`? (`int(math.ceil(100 * 2.55))` may be necessary for reasons of floating-point (im)precision)

Comment: no we cannot do like that, because IMAGE library support RGB(0-255) default color format, i just want to give percentage values on CMYK format!, it might be some methods to set a percentage values instead of RGB(0-255).hope you clear it.

Comment: Do you mean like http://stackoverflow.com/q/17234308/3001761?

Comment: yes, i have used already before,First CMYK values converted to RGB then converted that image to CMYK to save it, but it will save slightly different color what actually we needs!

Comment: Have you read the *comments* on that question? It sounds like the conversion is non-trivial, so maybe *"slightly different color"* is what you should have expected.

Comment: Yes but we have already a CMYK values so i don't need to convert that values to RGB, i thought,might be any method to assign those CMYK values directly as percentage!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you so much, finally we have done it easily with your first comment! i have tried to upvote for you! but i cant

Answer (score 0):

I see [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagecolor.htm) that for RGB, you can specify in percentages.

> RGB functions, given as “rgb(red, green, blue)” where the colour
>   values are integers in the range 0 to 255. Alternatively, the color
>   values can be given as three percentages (0% to 100%). For example,
>   “rgb(255,0,0)” and “rgb(100%,0%,0%)” both specify pure red.

Can you also try this for CMYK?